# Can ".htaccess" file work with npm's "http-server" command?

Tags: .htaccess, npm, httpserver

This is probably a rookie question, but although the [npm http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server) page states:

> ...http-server is a simple, zero-configuration command-line http server...

Does this mean it completely disregards an .htaccess file? If so, is there another (yet still simple to use) HTTP server alternative that reads and uses it?

Comment: `.htaccess` is an Apache thing. What do you need it for if you're using node?

Comment: Ah sorry, my misunderstanding. I've only been using node / npm to launch the `http-server`, but I need to handle this mime-type `AddType text/cache-manifest appcache manifest`. I've only found the .htaccess solution, if something similar exists for node, I can ask a different question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

.htaccess is an Apache configuration file. Since Apache isn't npm, Apache configuration files will obviously not work for npm.

Npm uses environment variables and npmrc files to configure things. See [this documentation page](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/config).

In your case it looks like that [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mime-types) might do what you want it to do.