# How to suppress files in http-server index?

Tags: node.js

On Mac there is a .DS_Store file in every directory. The `--no-dotfiles` option for [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server) conveniently omits all files beginning with a "." from the index generated on the front page.

Is there a comparable way to do this more generally for other files (for example, favicon.ico)?

Comment: You can google htaccess

Comment: sadly, htaccess [does not](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30259184/22673230) apply to http-server (a node package). thank you though!